# How can I use a boxstyle for pad and round for a rectangle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hello I have this code using Python and the module Matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

f = plt.figure()

gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1, figure=f)
gs00 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=gs0[0])

ax1 = f.add_subplot(gs00[:, :-1])
ax2 = f.add_subplot(gs00[:-1, -1])
ax3 = f.add_subplot(gs00[-1, -1])

ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
ax3.axis('off')

ax1.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax1", va="center", ha="center")
ax2.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax2", va="center", ha="center")
ax3.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax3", va="center", ha="center")

f.add_artist(plt.Rectangle((0.01, 0.01), 0.99, 0.99,
                  edgecolor = 'black', facecolor = 'orange',
                  fill = False, angle=40,
                  linewidth = 3, zorder = 1))
plt.show()
```

But I would like to use something like this in my rectangle `boxstyle='round,pad=1'`

because I have this :

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrhLg.png)

And I would like to have this :

[What I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jloE1.png)

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: A `Rectangle` doesn't have any "boxstyle". You will need a [`FancyBboxPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch) instead.

Comment: Thank you but with my figure how can I do this ?